# How to create a single View with 2 different, optional contextual filters?

Tags: 7, views

I need to check whether there is already a registered user having the same user email **or** username. Right now I have two Views (one with passing the username and one with passing the user email as contextual filter). When there is no user with the username, the second view is called.

There is the "allow multiple values" setting for the contextual filter, but this allows me to pass 2 emails, but not an email or a username for instance.

**Is there a way to create one View where the user enters a value (name or email) as filter?**

**SOLUTION:**

As suggested by Marco that works well:

[image]

Comment: You can create a view with a context filter for username and a context filter for usermail. Then check the input of the user, if it is a email adress. If it is a email you can redirect to the view and set the context filter for the username to "all" and the context filter for the mail to the user input. If it is no mail adress you can set the context filter for the usermail to "all" and the context filter of the username to the userinput and redirect to this path.

Comment: Thanks Marco. Why didnt you post this as answer? I gladly accept it.

Comment: I was not sure if this is what you search for. I provided my solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view with a context filter for username and a context filter for usermail.

Then check the input of the user, if it is a email adress. If it is a email you can redirect to the view and set the context filter for the username to "all" and the context filter for the mail to the user input.

If it is no mail adress you can set the context filter for the usermail to "all" and the context filter of the username to the userinput and redirect to this path.